# Why am I able to download this zip file only when I include the headers?

Tags: http, url, python-requests, get

I was trying to download a zip file from a URL using python and the requests library.
I searched how to do it and came up with this code:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(file_url)
file = open("file.zip","wb")
file.write(r.content)
file.close()
```

However when i tried opening the zip file it gave me an error saying it wasn't a zip file.
After searching a bit more I added headers to the request by copying the actual header data from the network tab of my browser when I hit the url from my browser, and it worked.
The headers i added were:

```
headers = {'Host': 'www.bseindia.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'DNT': '1',
'Alt-Used': 'www.bseindia.com',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
'Sec-GPC': '1'}
```

I want to know why this worked with the headers and not without, I am new to this so I have almost no knowledge of how the web works. Thanks for answering.

So i tried removing each header value to see which one was necessary and it seems the User-Agent value is important. Why so?